# How to create a real life-like 3D avatar with react-native?

Tags: react-native, 3d, avatar

This question can sound a bit off-topic or more of tech capacity or capability. Let's say I am pretty new to this whole thing. I recently came across with https://avatarsdk.com and http://tada-time.com and really got curious how they are doing it. Let's say I want to use a real life-like 3D avatar in a react native app, any ideas where to start with? How do I create an avatar in React Native app?
I am well aware of there are API we can pay and use it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why there's a downvote for this question? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what your requirement is to create 3D objects for Augmented reality, if I am correct. Currently Apple and Android provides their own framework for that. IOS's AR kit and android's AR Core is a bit different in terms of code structure(I mean how they approach problems, their functionality etc). I'll consider them a bit advance topic better done on native platforms. Answering your question, I haven't come across any such library in react native and I don't think we'll see any soon as react native is still maturing and still has a lot to do to become stable.

I've seen projects in react native having AR elements, but that was done entirely in native and bridged to react native (hybrid)